# How to use user selected variable in shiny with 2 steps

Tags: r, shiny

I include reproducible example here. I want user to pick a variable which will be passed as argument to group_by function. Then I want to plot the aggregated data. While I was able to find how to refer to user input while I am calculating aggregation later when I want to refer to the same variable in chart I don't know how to do it. In my example I need to find right answer for placeholder xxxxxxxxxxx or perhaps find different solution

````
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(



      selectInput("first","Select variable",c("cyl","gear")),




    plotOutput("distPlot")

)


server <- function(input, output) {


  data<-reactive({
  mtcars%>%group_by(!!input$first)%>%summarise(average=mean())
  })



  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(data(),aes(XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,average))+
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)```
````

Comment: Which is the variable for which you want to take the `mean`? You are just specifying `mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference input$first in the `group_by` function and in ggplot's `aes` function you have to write `!!sym(input$first)`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("first","Select variable",c("cyl","gear")),
  plotOutput("distPlot"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data<-reactive({
    mtcars%>% 
      group_by(!!sym(input$first)) %>%
      summarise(average=mean(mpg))
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data(),aes(x=!!sym(input$first),y=average)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To see why you need `sym` consider the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("first","Select variable",c("cyl","gear")),
  tableOutput("wrong"),
  tableOutput("correct")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$wrong <- renderTable({
    mtcars%>% 
      group_by(!!input$first) %>%
      summarise(average=mean(mpg))
  })

  output$correct <- renderTable({
    mtcars%>% 
      group_by(!!sym(input$first)) %>%
      summarise(average=mean(mpg))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Just added a shiny app that demonstrates why the original approach does not produce the desired results